# Shared Contacts from a Mailbox in outlook Permissions

Tags: iphone, outlook, exchange-server

I have a problem with a shared user account that I need some help with:

In outlook, we use a user mailbox for our company contacts that I have restricted to be only accessible by a few people. Problem is that some people need access to this and we put the account on their phone, but then they have full control and can add and remove contacts at will.

Is there a way to restrict (for example an iPhone) access to the outlook account to be read only?

I have tried using the ECP (no applicable settings) and made the user a "reviewer" to their own box, but the phone still has full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with access from a phone is that the build and applications and even the Outlook app for iPhone and Android doesn't have the ability to access Shared Mailboxes.

So the only way of getting it working on a phone, outside of having the users open the webmail which is not a nice experience on a mobile devices despite Microsofts best efforts, is to give the mailbox an Exchange license and provide the user with a username and password for the mailbox.

However doing this will give the user full access to all folders in the mailbox.

I would recommend a solution like
[CiraSync](https://www.cirasync.com/public-folder-sync/), where you could sync contacts between folders directly to the users own mailbox or from the GAL directly to the users.

I would recommend other vendors that does the same but this is the only vendor that I have tested myself on customers and I have good experiences with.